# How to do "Surround-with" to a selected word with free-text(not predefined) in Visual Studio 2010, like in Vim

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, vim, code-snippets, vsvim

Like in Vim after install Surround plugin, user can select a word and then press "s" key, then input a tag or any free-text he want to use to surround the selected word.

I know in Visual Studio you can press c-k c-s to wake up a surround-with snippets selection, but they are predefine tags, is there a way to let user type the tag on the fly? or does VS snippets support this, any example?

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own templates to do what your asking

take a look at the docs

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hf704tz(v=vs.80).aspx